# Как задать кодировку значениям массива?

Tags: php, кодировка

Как побороть такую ситуацию. Скрипт отображается правильно, но на почту приходят квадратики. Все файлы вроде бы в одной кодировке, в чем проблема?
Причем заголовок приходит нормальный, а тело письма частично правильное, частично кривое.

### UPD

Выяснил следующее: есть некий массив с названиями полей, которые заполняют пользователи в форме.

```
$profiles = array(
    'calculator' => array(
        'subject' => 'Заказ',
        'fields' => array(
            'name' => 'Имя',
            'phone' => 'Телефон',
            'date' => 'День звонка',
            'time' => 'Время звонка',
            'message' => 'Комментарий',
            'tovar' => 'Товар'
        ),
        'message' => array(
            'success' => 'Ваша заявка успешно отправлена.'
        )
    )
);
```

Так вот именно эти `Имя`, `Телефон` и т.д. приходят кривые. Сами значения нормальные. Есть, конечно, тупой способ написать их в транслите Name Phone и т.д. Но это не вариант для патриота своей страны. )))

Подскажите, как задать кодировку этим полям?

Comment: Привидите пример кода отправки писем. Если письмо отправляется как text/html то там должна быть указана кодировка

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю вам [iconv](http://www.php.su/iconv) нужен.

Comment: А можно подробнее, как значениям массива fields установить кодировку?

Comment: @Batyabest

    foreach ($profiles['fields'] as $key => $value) {
        $profiles['fields'][$key] = iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8", $value);
    }

Comment: Все равно приходят крякозяблики. Кодировку показывает ANSII

Comment: @Batyabest
В примере я показал, перекодировку из windows-1251 в utf-8.
Определитесь какая у вас реально исходная кодировка и какая вам нужна и измените пример соответственно.

Comment: Я немного ошибся. Переменная $profiles в кодировке ASCII. Я так понимаю, в UTF-8 ее не перевести, потому что в ней в принципе нет символов кириллицы? Где тогда исправить нужно?